# SQL cross-joining to produce number sequence 

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've tried to figure out how this SQL query generates a sequence of numbers, and I still don't have a clue.

**Digits Table**

```
digit
--------
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9


SELECT D3.digit * 100 + D2.digit * 10 + D1.digit + 1 AS n
FROM    dbo.Digits as D1
CROSS JOIN dbo.Digits as D2
CROSS JOIN dbo.Digits AS D3
ORDERY BY n;
```

**The Query Result...**

```
n
------
1
2
3
4
5
...
998
999
1000
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[CROSS JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx) is much like an `INNER JOIN MYTable on 1 = 1`, resulting in the Cartesian Product of your Input Sets**

Basically, for each record on the left, it joins for each record on the right.

In the case of a 10-digit source table, the first cross join results in 100 records.

In the case of a second cross join to the same 10-digit source table, you get all 100 previous records again, for each record in the source table, resulting in 1000 records.

**Your resulting table would look like this, if you your Select Statement was "Select * ..." Order by ...**

```
D1    D2    D3
1     2     3
1     2     4
1     2     5
```

**If you take those values in the table above and concatenate them (then add one) you get consecutive numbers.**

```
"1" + "2" + "3" = 123  (+1 = 124)
"1" + "2" + "4" = 124  (+1 = 125)
"1" + "2" + "5" = 125  (+1 = 126)
```

**Obviously, the author is not concatenating. However, he's doing the mathematical equivalent.**

```
1 * 100 + 2 * 10 + 3 * 1 + 1 = 124
1 * 100 + 2 * 10 + 4 * 1 + 1 = 125
1 * 100 + 2 * 10 + 5 * 1 + 1 = 126
```

Ultimately, the author devised a strange way to provide a listing of numbers from 1 to 1000.

Answer (score 3):

If you are into CTE, this will give you 1 to 1000.

```
;
with
Num(Pos) as
(
    select cast(1 as int)
    union all 
    select cast(Pos + 1 as int) from Num where Pos < 1000
)
select * from Num option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

A [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_join#Cross_join) is a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product): that is, every row joins with every other row.

So a 11 row table joined to a 7 row table gives 77 rows

In your case, you have 10 rows * 10 rows * 10 rows = 1000.

Try this query to see the raw date before you generate the number

```
SELECT D3.digit, D2.digit, D1.digit
FROM    dbo.Digits as D1
CROSS JOIN dbo.Digits as D2
CROSS JOIN dbo.Digits AS D3
ORDER BY d3, d2, d1;
```

The way you have `100*d3 + 10*d2 + d1` replicates how we count naturally and carry in addition.

Comment: Yes I understand that but how does it generate the actual numbers? 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. ??

Answer (score 1):

The values of the digit from the D3 table will range from 0 - 900 (D3.digit * 100)

The values of the digit from the D2 table will range from 0 - 90 (D2.digit * 10)

The values of the digit from the D1 table will range from 0 - 9 (D1.digit * 100)

Add them up and you have a range from 0 - 999

Add 1 to the result and you have a range from 1 - 1000